# How to get the current post being viewed from the aw_blog extension

Tags: template, header

I have the following code in template/page/html/head.phtml, and for social network sharing I need access to the blogpost content so I can extract the images from the blogposts.

```
$post = Mage::getSingleton('blog/cat')->load(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('post_id', Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id', false))))
$page = $post->getContent();
```

but this doens't give me the content of the current blogpost being viewed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, under the motto of "hack the world" I pieced together this code myself:

```
if($content = Mage::getSingleton('blog/post')->getData('post_content'))
   {
   $blog_content = Mage::helper('cms')->getPageTemplateProcessor()->filter($content);
   //do what needs to be done.
   }
```